# Не должно быть 3 и более подряд идущих одинаковых символа

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Задание:

> Разработать модуль, который будет проверять корректность ввода пароля
>
> Пароль должен отвечать следующим требованиям:
>
> - должен содержать от 6 символов,
> - не должно быть символов из набора: * & { } | +,
> - должны встречаться незаглавные буквы,
> - не должно быть 3 и более подряд идущих одинаковых символа,
> - могут встречаться цифры.
>
> Для реализации алгоритма нужно разработать отдельный метод.

Возникли трудности именно с 4 пунктом(не должно быть 3 и более подряд идущих одинаковых символа), вот что есть на данный момент:

```
string password = textBox1.Text;
Regex pravilo1 = new Regex(@"[*&{}|+,]+");
Regex pravilo2 = new Regex(@"[A-Z]+");
Regex pravilo3 = new Regex(@"[a-z]+");
Regex pravilo4 = new Regex(@"[0-9]+");
if (password.Length >= 6 && pravilo2.IsMatch(password) && pravilo3.IsMatch(password)
  && pravilo4.IsMatch(password) != pravilo1.IsMatch(password))
    MessageBox.Show("True");
else
    MessageBox.Show("False");
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Что именно вам непонятно в задании? Вы умеете делать отдельный метод?

Comment: покажите что вы сделали самостоятельно, и в чем у вас возникли трудности!

Comment: Возникли трудности именно с 4 пунктом(не должно быть 3 и более подряд идущих одинаковых символа), вот что есть на данный момент:

Comment: string password = textBox1.Text;
            Regex pravilo1 = new Regex(@"[*&{}|+,]+");
            Regex pravilo2 = new Regex(@"[A-Z]+");
            Regex pravilo3 = new Regex(@"[a-z]+");
            Regex pravilo4 = new Regex(@"[0-9]+");
            if (password.Length >= 6 && pravilo2.IsMatch(password) && pravilo3.IsMatch(password) && pravilo4.IsMatch(password) != pravilo1.IsMatch(password)) MessageBox.Show("True");
            else MessageBox.Show("False");

Comment: Пожалуйста, помещайте всё необходимое в текст вопроса, под ним есть кнопочка "править"

Comment: morelinq-вариант: `password.Window(3).All(w => w.Distinct().Count() > 1)`

Answer (score 2):

> не должно быть 3 и более подряд идущих одинаковых символа

```
private bool ThreeLettersCheck(string password)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < password.Length - 2; i++)
        if (password[i] == password[i + 1] && password[i] == password[i + 2])
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Раз уж делаете каждое правило отдельной регуляркой — вот вам выражение для п. 4:

```
var pattern = @"(.)\1{2}";
string[] input = { "111", "123", "aaa", "qwerty", "qqwweerrttyy", "qweeerty" };
foreach (var s in input)
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern));
```

Вывод:

```
True
False
True
False
False
True
```

Объяснение: в регулярке можно использовать уже захваченные группы, `(.)` — захватывает любой символ, `\1{2}` — еще 2 повторения первой группы, т. е. того, что захватило выражение `(.)`

Comment: три символа подряд регуляркой? оно же медленное :)

Comment: @tym32167, пользователь устанет ждать, пока его пароль проверяется 100 мс вместо 10? Ну а вообще, раз уж у ТС регулярки, логично ими и продолжить :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP вероятно нужно в скобках уточняющего квантификатора, после цифры 2 поставить запятую -- что бы шаблон соответствовал условию "_3 и более..._" `"(.)\1{2,}"`

Comment: @Эдуард, зачем? Может и контрпример приведете? Если строка содержит 4, 5 или 100 одинаковых символов подряд, то она уж точно содержит 3 символа подряд

Comment: @АндрейNOP на C# не приведу, я так-то пхпшник ) Мне не принципиально, просто ваш шаблон немного не соответствует условию. Но ваше замечание из комментария тоже верно.  Единственный аргумент в пользу запятой - скорость обработки _(с запятой немного быстрее)_

Comment: А что не вписали свой вариант из комментов к вопросу?

Comment: @AK, да что-то как-то постеснялся :)

Answer (score 0):

Получается так: `var pattern = @"^(([^*&{}|+])(?<!\2{3,})){6,}(?<=\p{Ll}.*?)$"`

Для начала берём `[^*&{}|+]`, что соответствует второму условию:

> - не должно быть символов из набора: * & { } | +,

В принципе это не противоречит условиям:

> - должны встречаться незаглавные буквы,
> - могут встречаться цифры.

Далее, отрабатываем условие:

> - должен содержать от 6 символов,

Добавляем диапазон `{6,}` и устанавливаем границы строки (`^` и `$`):

```
^[^*&{}|+]{6,}$
```

Далее, отрабатываем:

> - не должно быть 3 и более подряд идущих одинаковых символа,

Для этого используем ретроспективную отрицательную проверку `?<!` и ссылку на предыдущую группу `\2` c диапазоном `{3,}` - `(?<!\2{3,})`:

```
^(([^*&{}|+])(?<!\2{3,})){6,}$
```

Отрабатываем:

> - должны встречаться незаглавные буквы

Для этого используем дополнительную ретроспективную проверку `?<=` с свойством юникода `\p{Ll}` - `(?<=\p{Ll}.*?)` и вставляем это в позицию конец строки `$`:

```
^(([^*&{}|+])(?<!\2{3,})){6,}(?<=\p{Ll}.*?)$
```

И того:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] input = { "aaa", "qwerty", "qweeerty", "QQWWEERRTTYY", "12345678", "a12345678", "q&werty" };

    foreach (var s in input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"s: {s}");

        Console.WriteLine($"Success: {IsValid(s)}");

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

static bool IsValid(string password)
{
    var pattern = @"^(([^*&{}|+])(?<!\2{3,})){6,}(?<=\p{Ll}.*?)$";
    return Regex.IsMatch(password, pattern);
}
```

Вывод:

```
s: aaa
Success: False

s: qwerty
Success: True

s: qweeerty
Success: False

s: QQWWEERRTTYY
Success: False

s: 12345678
Success: False

s: a12345678
Success: True

s: q&werty
Success: False
```